# Calculate the Survival prediction using Cox Proportional Hazard model in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to calculate the Survival prediction using Cox Proportional Hazard model in R.

```
    library(survival)
    data(lung)
    model<-coxph(Surv(time,status ==2)~age + sex + ph.karno + wt.loss, data=lung)
    predict(model, data=lung, type ="expected")
```

When I use the above code, I get the Cumulative hazard's prediction corresponding to the formula

```
    h^i(t)=h^0(t)exp(x′iβ^)
```

But my concern is all about predicting the Survival corresponding to the formula,

```
    S^i(t)=S^0(t)exp(x′iβ^)
```

How do I predict the Survival in R?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you figured how to do prediction? I have the exact same question and I don't think the answer can provide probability.

Comment: I have calculated the survival like this in R, 
        exp(-predict)
where predict is the predicted value of newdata using predict() function

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Just want to check which type of prediction you meant here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use either `predict` or `survfit`. With `predict` you need to give the newdata argument a list with values for all the variables in the model:

```
predict(model, 
      newdata=list(time=100,status=1,age=60,sex=1, ph.karno=60,wt.loss=15),
      type ="expected")
[1] 0.2007497
```

There's a plot method for survfit objects:

```
?survreg
png(); plot(survfit(model)); dev.off()
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain me what this plot means?

Comment: [1] 0.2007497 
Does this outcome mean the survival rate?

Comment: The survival function does not return rates. Rates are counts/number_at_risk/unit_time. Survival functions return proportions. 0.020 is the estimated survival proportion for a cohort with the features entered in the `newdata` argument.

Comment: Does using type = "risk" allow one to score observations by level of risk? Could this be used as an indicator that an event is likely to occur soon or how is the output interpreted? Thanks.

Comment: Setting type="risk" for the `predict.coxph`-function gets you the risk score, i.e. `exp(lp)` which can also be called the hazard ratio or relative hazard, where `lp` is the linear predictor for either the original data points or a hypothetical set of points delivered to the function by a list-object of `newdata` values. Higher risk scores are associated with earlier events or equivalently shorter median survivals.

Comment: Cautionary note: The 'type' parameter for survfit and coxph models has very different values (e.g. "right", "left", "counting") than does the 'type' parameter for `predict.coxph`.