# Extimate prediction accuracy of cox ph

Tags: r, cox-regression, survival

i would like to develop a [cox proportional hazard model](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cox-Regression) with r, use it to predict input and evaluate the accuracy of the model. For the evaluation I would like to use the [Brior score](http://www.statisticshowto.com/brier-score/).

```
# import various packages, needed at some point of the script
library("survival")
library("survminer")
library("prodlim")
library("randomForestSRC")
library("pec")
library("rpart")
library("mlr")
library("Hmisc")
library("ipred")

# load lung cancer data
data("lung")
head(lung)

# recode status variable 
lung$status <- lung$status-1

# Delete rows with missing values
lung <- na.omit(lung)

# split data into training and testing
## 80% of the sample size
smp_size <- floor(0.8 * nrow(lung))

## set the seed to make your partition reproducible
set.seed(123)
train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(lung)), size = smp_size)

# training and testing data
train.lung <- lung[train_ind, ]
test.lung <- lung[-train_ind, ]

# time and failure event
s <- Surv(train.lung$time, train.lung$status)
# create model
cox.ph2 <- coxph(s~age+meal.cal+wt.loss, data=train.lung)

# predict 
pred <- predict(cox.ph2, newdata = train.lung)

# evaluate 
sbrier(s, pred)
```

as an outcome of the prediction I would expect the time (as in "when does this individuum experience failure). Instead I get values like this

```
[1]  0.017576359 -0.135928959 -0.347553969  0.112509137 -0.229301199 -0.131861582  0.044589175  0.002634008
[9]  0.345966978  0.209488560  0.002418358
```

What does that mean?

Furthermore sbrier does not work. Apparently it can not work with the prediction pred (no surprise there)

How do I solve this? How do I make a prediction with cox.ph2? How can I evaluate the model afterwards?

Answer (score 2):

The `predict()` function won't return a time value, you have to specify the argument `type = c("lp", "risk","expected","terms","survival")` in the `predict()` function.

If you want to get the hazard ratios :

```
predict(cox.ph2, newdata = test.lung, type = "risk")
```

Note that you want to predict the values on the test set not the training set.

I have read that you can use AFT models in your case : 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79362/how-to-get-predictions-in-terms-of-survival-time-from-a-cox-ph-model

You also can read this post :
[Calculate the Survival prediction using Cox Proportional Hazard model in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27228256/calculate-the-survival-prediction-using-cox-proportional-hazard-model-in-r)

Hope it will help

Comment: Thank you. That already helped a lot. Could you also tell me how to get the brier score for the model?

Comment: Never heard about this score but you should have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42583087/estimating-prediction-accuracy-of-a-cox-survival-model-using-sbrier-r